# Onscreen keyboard missing

Tags: 18.04, onscreen-keyboard

On two machines, I tried to enable onscreen keyboard using Accessibility option. The option looks enabled, but there is no onscreen keyboard visible. Is it some bug ? Using default 18.04 fully updated.

Comment: after seeing this question, i tried it in my Ubuntu 18.04.. same problem.

Comment: This is reported as a bug and looks like it is fixed now. I got a few emails about it.